# Fail to locate j_spring_security_check in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-security, web.xml

I am working on spring Security, I am facing the issue "Problem accessing /CustomRole/j_spring_security_check"

My web.xml file is as follow

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true"
    use-expressions="true">
    <!-- When access is refused, will go to the 403.jsp -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" filters="none" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.action"
        default-target-url="/index.jsp"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
    <sec:http-basic />
    <!-- An increase in filter and Acegi, this is not the same, can not modify 
        the default filter, the filter is located in the FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR 
        before> -->
    <sec:custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"
        ref="myFilter" />
</sec:http>

<!-- A custom filter, you must include the authenticationManager, accessDecisionManager, 
    securityMetadataSource three attributes, All control we will achieve in the 
    three class, explain the specific configuration, see> -->
<beans:bean id="myFilter"
    class="com.demo.security.MyFilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="myAccessDecisionManagerBean" />
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="securityMetadataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- The authentication manager, entrance for user authentication, which 
    implements the UserDetailsService interface can be -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService">
        <!-- If the user's password using encryption, you can add a little salt 
            "" <password-encoder hash="md5"/> -->
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailService" class="com.demo.security.MyUserDetailService" />

<!-- Access decision device, determines whether a user has a role, that 
    you have sufficient permissions to access a resource -->
<beans:bean id="myAccessDecisionManagerBean" class="com.demo.security.MyAccessDecisionManager">
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resource source data definition, the definition of a resource can be 
    what role access -->
<beans:bean id="securityMetadataSource"
    class="com.demo.security.MyInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" />
```

After hitting the launch page it open login page successfully.But when i provide login credential and try to hit login it fails and throw error related to "j_spring_security_check"

I have created code as per the available on http://www.programering.com/a/MTNygjMwATY.html

Comment: Well of course you changed it to `/j_spring_security_check.action`.

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum for reply,But I am not getting can you explain

Comment: You configured the `login-processing-url` which is the url which you must use for submission of username/password. You set it to something different yourself.

Comment: login-processing-url="/home.jsp"  i update with Home jps file but getting the same issue/error

Comment: Have you actually read my comment? You have configured the URL to be `/j_spring_security_check.action`, your form is posting to `/j_spring_security_check`. You can change it to whatever you like but the form has to send the request to the correct URL.

Comment: The forma which i added is in future use, i have remove that form and try to run the application but facing same issue.I am able to see the login page but as per sample spring security it will call the security check but here my application/i am unable to find that.

Comment: I give up, you fail to read my comments or understand them. Your URLs don't match and never will if you keep changing one and never the other.